# Problems with Django when trying to show error message when form insn't valid

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

### Description

In my application i have a user registration form, but, when simulating not following the recommendations for form validation, i get an httpresponse error. But, what i'm trying to do is display an error message using the message framework from django

[image: Error page]

### Code

#### My template

```
{% block body %}
    {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
            <div class="text-center alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
                {{ message|safe }}
             </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

    {% load crispy_forms_tags %}

    <form class = "" method="post" action="{% url 'registro' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{registro_form|crispy}}
            <button class = "btn btn-primary" type="submit">Registrar</button>
    </form>

   
{% endblock body %}
```

#### My Form

```
class NovoUsuarioForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email']

    def save(self, commit = True):
        user = super(NovoUsuarioForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.username = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name'] 

        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

#### My View

```
class RegistroView(generic.View):
    def get(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'main/registro.html', {'registro_form': NovoUsuarioForm()})

    def post(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = NovoUsuarioForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            login(request,user)
            messages.success(request, "Registration successful." )
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('pesquisa'))
        messages.error(request, "Unsuccessful registration. Invalid information.")
```

### Other Info

When i go back to the form page, from the error page after the post method, i get the error message

[image: Page after going back from the error]

Answer (score 0):

Your view does not return an HTTP response if the form is NOT valid; the view does not have a `return` for that case, so it returns `None`.

This is the overview for your code:

```
class RegistroView(generic.View):
    ...

    def post(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        if form.is_valid():
            ...
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('pesquisa'))

        ...
```

I suggest adding something like `return HttpResponse(...)` for the case when the form is not valid. The exact think you return depends on your use case.